# pppd issue over serial cable

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, pppd

I'm trying to set up a ppp connection between 2 computers via serial cable, to enable TCP/IP over serial.

Computer1 -> USB-Serial Converter -> Serial Cable -> Serial port of Computer 2

On computer 2 (running Fedora as root), I type :

```
pppd /dev/ttyS0 115200 lock nodetach noauth debug 195.0.0.12:195.0.0.13
```

It just hangs there.

On computer 1 (running CentOS 6.5 as root), I type:

```
pppd /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 lock nodetach noauth debug
```

it shows ...

```
using channel 23
using interface ppp0 
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0 
sent ... 
..
..
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated. 
Modem hangup.
```

I'm unable to ping the other computer from either computer.

What could be the issue here?

UPDATE:

Now on Computer 2, I plug in a USB-Serial converter instead of using /dev/ttyS0 . It works now, I have no idea why though.

so now:

Computer1 -> USB-Serial Converter -> Serial Cable ->Serial-USB Converter -> Computer 2 (usb port)

Maybe genuine serial ports don't play well with USB-Serial over pppd?

Comment: Are you using a correct (reverse or cross) cable?  And you might need `local` on both ends.

Comment: Yes, I've tried minicom-ing each other and it works.

Comment: Is a `getty` or serial console working on `/dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: @yaegashi nope...sorry what do you mean by "local"?

Comment: Just add it to pppd arguments: `pppd /dev/ttyS0 115200 local lock nodetach ...`

Comment: @lppier Did you ever end up solving this problem?