# pppd "Couldn't get channel number: Input/output error"

Tags: embedded, serial-port, pppd

I have two USB-serial adapters with a null-modem serial cable between them, similar [to this user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218780/pppd-issue-over-serial-cable). I can setup an IP connection easily between two linux (ubuntu) boxes running this [pppd](/questions/tagged/pppd) command on one side:

```
pppd -detach crtscts lock 10.2.10.2:10.2.10.2 /dev/ttyUSB0 38400 &
```

and this on the other:

```
pppd -detach crtscts lock 10.2.10.1:10.2.10.1 /dev/ttyUSB0 38400 &
```

However, running the same command between a linux box and an embedded linux device ([sama5d3x-mb](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel_11180_32-bit-cortex-a5-microcontroller_sama5d3-series-ek_user-guide.pdf)) I receive the following error message:

```
Couldn't get channel number: Input/output error
```

This message can appear on either the desktop linux side or the embedded linux side, it just depends on which end the first command is issued. I also occasionally see this message:

```
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

Obviously something isn't setup correctly in the embedded environment. These are the only error messages that appear in the log.

If I instead open up the serial ports using putty/screen I can tx/rx characters back and forth just fine.

One thing I noticed is that on my desktop system I have a folder at `/etc/ppp` that contains many files. Such a folder does not exist on the embedded environment. I tried dumping a copy there with rsync. However, their presence doesn't seem to make a difference.

Both the deskop and embedded platform report `pppd version 2.4.5`

Google results mostly turn to [dead ends](http://www.edaboard.com/thread22080.html). Short of browsing through the [pppd](/questions/tagged/pppd) source code, or setting up a sniffer to inspect for any traffic on the lines, I'm sure not where to go from here. Any recommendations?